Invalid Executable. The executable 'appname.app/Frameworks/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal' contains bitcode. (ID: XXXX)
I get this error trying to upload an archived app to Apple Store.
This error appears after update to MacOS: Sequioa 15.0 and XCode 16.
Error print
I tryed to downgrade XCode, but it seems to not be possible with Sequoia.
I have found some people saying to run a comand like "xcrun bitcode_strip <file>", but I don't know witch file should I pass.

It happen on macOS Sonoma too

I had the same problem.
I fixed it by upgrading react-native-onesignal from version 4.3.8 to 5.2.4.
The migration guide for this upgrade is available at https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal/blob/major_release_5.0.0/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md.

I encountered the same problem. In order to resolve this issue, you need to strip the bitcode present in your OneSignal package. You can use the following command inside your bash terminal:
 xcrun bitcode_strip -r OneSignal.framework/OneSignal -o OneSignal.framework/OneSignal

If you want to read the solution in detail, then you can read my full article posted on Medium.

I encountered the same problem. My temporary solution was to revert to Xcode 15.4. I’ll leave you with some more information.
Invalid Executable. The executable 'appname.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework/hermes' contains bitcode. (ID: XXXX)
